# Generating a SWING/Gui from Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate, swing, code-generation

is there any tool that would read a something like a [hibernate mapping file](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html) and would then create some stubs of java code for a java Swing client ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If your model consists of Java beans, try [MetaWidget](http://metawidget.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly what you asked for the implementations of the Naked Objects architectural pattern might be of interest:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naked_objects